# How do I install the Malvern font in Tex Live 2015?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, metafont, installing-fonts

I am attempting to install the [`Malvern`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/malvern/) font from Tug, and am running on Ubuntu 16.04.

First off, if there is an automatic way to do this, please let me know what that might be.

Second, I have followed the [following instructions](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall-personal.html) to try to install the font.

Here is a minimum document.

```
\documentclass{report}

\input T1fmv.fd
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{fmv}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Here is the error I receive.

```
pathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ma55a10
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ma55a10.
mktexpk: perhaps ma55a10 is missing from the map file.
```

Finally, most of the instructions I found refer to finding some kind of `map` file, but there does not appear to be a map file associated with Malvern.

**How can I install Malvern?**

Comment: Did you also install the Metafont sources? Note that for this font there is no map, as it is only available in bitmap form

Comment: I attempted to install them by copying into the source directory,  but I do not know if that constitutes a correct installation.

Comment: It took a few minutes to do the installation on my machine, I'm glad it works also on yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fonts are only available in bitmap source.

The directory `fonts/malvern` on CTAN has a few subdirectories. Assuming you want to use `TEXMFHOME` (which is `~/texmf` on GNU/Linux systems and `~/Library/texmf` on Mac OS X), you have to place the various subdirectories in the following way, where `$TEXMFHOME` denotes the suitable root determined as before.

```
contrib/        → $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/contrib/
doc/            → $TEXMFHOME/doc/fonts/malvern/doc/
drivers/        → $TEXMFHOME/fonts/source/malvern/drivers/
source/         → $TEXMFHOME/fonts/source/malvern/source/
tex/OT1fmv.fd   → $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/OT1fmv.fd
tex/OT1fmv9.fd  → $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/OT1fmv9.fd
tex/T1fmv.fd    → $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/T1fmv.fd
tex/T1fmv9.fd   → $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/T1fmv9.fd
tex/maamac.tex  → $TEXMFHOME/tex/plain/malvern/maamac.tex
tex/pdcutil.tex → $TEXMFHOME/tex/plain/malvern/pdcutil.tex
tfm/            → $TEXMFHOME/fonts/tfm/malvern/
vf/             → $TEXMFHOME/fonts/vf/malvern/
```

In the left column, the trailing `/` denotes that the whole directory should be moved in the indicated position (with possible change of name like in the last two cases). The files in `tex/` should be moved in different places. Missing directories should be created.

The rest of the distribution is pretty useless. Also move the files in the `dvi` directory inside `$TEXMFHOME/doc/fonts/malvern/doc`.

I did, in a Bash shell,

```
TEXMFHOME=$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME)
```

Then

```
mkdir -p $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/ ; mv contrib $TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/malvern/
```

and so on for the other directories.

Here's the test file

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand*\sfdefault{fmv}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One thing I am curious about; where did you find documentation on where to put everything? I think the instructions I followed before seemed to imply that it was sufficient to mirror the directory structure inside the zip archive.

Comment: @merlin2011 I made it up using my experience in similar cases; the structure of TeX Live has changed a bit since the fonts were released.